# How to send a proper HTTP request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, request

I've an ready made link that will send an SMS message to user's phone with THE OTP.

However, I'm using this way and I'm wondering if there is a better way to send the request. Also, how to make sure that I got an 200 OK response.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

response.Close();
```

Comment: What is "THE OTP"?

Comment: A better way is to use HttpClient, especially in .NET Core and the upcoming .NET 5. To ensure you got a 200 response, just check the response's status.

Comment: Hey @UweKeim , thanks for your quick response. OTP stands for one time password.

Comment: Hey @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for your quick response! Got it, but just to check if there is any better practices.

Comment: _" just to check if there is any better practices"_ using HttpClient (correctly!) _is_ the better practice.

Comment: Thanks! That's means a lot. @Fildor

Comment: I already answered that. Use HttpClient *correctly* - that means use async code instead of blocking, check the response status code etc. Synchronous HTTP calls block a thread for no reason, as the machine is just waiting for a response from another machine. Blocking doesn't mean the CPU isn't use, quite the opposite. Putting a thread to sleep and rescheduling is expensive so .NET tries a spinwait first before rescheduling the blocked thread. That means blocking results in *more* CPU usage

Comment: BTW, why we stress "correctly" in conjunction with HttpClient is because it is Disposable, people are tempted to use `using HttpClient client = new HttpClient...` which is really _only_ "ok" for some dumb example or experiment. In Production code, that will lead straight to hell. Read the docs carefully, there are (correct) examples linked and I think I've even seen links to related articles. In doubt just google "you are using HttpClient wrong".

Comment: See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client#send-a-get-request-to-retrieve-a-resource) for an example of what your requirement would look like with HttpClient.

Comment: Dear @PanagiotisKanavos , thanks a lot for sharing this information i totally forgot about the CPU!

Comment: @Fildor , Why in production will lead to hell? As i've learned  `using` in coding are good because once the system impalement a block of code and finishes it will destroy or end the connection. Anyhow, thanks for sharing the article i will check it out.

Comment: @sal_ Using `using` is a good idea 99.9% of the time. With `HttpClient` it's that one exception from the rule. Here, it can (and will sooner or later) lead to "socket exhaustion". The docs say: _"HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and re-used throughout the life of an application. Instantiating an HttpClient class for every request will exhaust the number of sockets available under heavy loads. This will result in SocketException errors."_

Comment: Oh! That's really GOOD to know!!! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HttpClient.

Example:

```
public class Client
{
  HttpClient _httpClient;
  public Client()
  {
    _httpClient=new HttpClient();
  }
  //async post,get request
  public async Task<string> sendGetRequest(string url)
  {
    var response= await _httpClient.GetAsync(url);
    if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
     //if response has status code 200 do something
     //in this case I'm just converting the content of the response in string format
      string result=await response.Content.ReadStringAsync();
    }
    else
    {
      return "error";
    }
  }
  public async Task<string> sendPostRequest(string url,string bodyJson)
  {
    //Example sending a post request with json as body.
    var body=new StringContent(bodyJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response= await _httpClient.PostAsync(url,body);
    if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
     //if response has status code 200 do something
     //in this case I'm just converting the contntent of the response in string format
      string result=await response.Content.ReadStringAsync();
      return result;
    }
    else
    {
     return "error";
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Dear, Thank you so much for sharing. It's much better and it's really helpful!